# if marks > TotalMarks: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, printing

helping my cousin fix some code, trying to figure out if its in this part of the code, something i need to fix the error. he's trying to make the code where it says:

heres the error

```
    while total_marks < marks:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

```
    while total_marks < marks:
        print('Invalid entry')
        marks = len(input('Re-enter the mark'))
    marks.append(marks)
```

is where the error is I think.

```
# Question 6
def q6():
    print("This is question 6!!!\n")
    print("Student grades\n")
    num_students = int(input("How many students would you like to enter?"))
    total_marks = int(input("What is the total number of marks a student can get?"))
    names = []
    marks = []
    for i in range(num_students):
        names.append(input("Name"))
        marks.append(int(input("grade")))

    while total_marks < marks:
        print('Invalid entry')
        marks = len(input('Re-enter the mark'))
    marks.append(marks)

    percent: int[Any] = []
    for i in range(len(marks)):
        percent.append(marks[i] / total_marks * 100)

    grade = []
    for i in range(len(percent)):
        if 90 <= percent <= 100:
            grade.append("H1")
        elif 80 <= percent <= 89:
            grade.append("H2")
        elif 70 <= percent <= 79:
            grade.append("H3")
        elif 60 <= percent <= 69:
            grade.append("H4")
        elif 50 <= percent <= 59:
            grade.append("H5")
        elif 40 <= percent <= 49:
            grade.append("H6")
        elif 30 <= percent <= 39:
            grade.append("H7")
        elif 0 <= percent <= 29:
            grade.append("H8")
    for i in range(num_students):
        print(names[i])
```

Comment: Is it because you forgot to sum the `marks` while comparing?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say our marks list is like this:
`marks = [12,10,30,50,80]`
and the total marks are 80
`total_marks = 80`

Now if we run this:

```
while total_marks < marks:
        <stuff>
```

What we're telling python to do is:
Compare the value 120 to a list of [12,10,30,50,80]

Since python doesn't know to look through the values inside the list, you can see how this produces the error you are getting.
*(Note some popular modules like NumPy have the ability to do this.

[Read the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/) for them if you want to do some research on that)*

You'll find a solution to this by going through all the values in the list and comparing each one to `total_marks`

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your marks comparison in the `while loop`
Here `marks` is a list and can have multiple values in it. If you want to compare whole values with the `total_marks`you can use `sum` of list.

Check the code:

You have made mistakes in two other places too.

1. Variable has to mentioned instead of whole list ## `marks[i]`

```
for i in range(len(marks)):
        percent.append(marks[i] / total_marks * 100)
```

Here `i` must be value, not a list.

2. Same as above you mentioned list reference in the grade assignment loop. I have replaced `percent` with the `j`.

```
def q6():
    print("This is question 6!!!\n")
    print("Student grades\n")
    num_students = int(input("How many students would you like to enter?"))
    total_marks = int(input("What is the total number of marks a student can get?"))
    names = []
    marks = []
    for i in range(num_students):
        names.append(input("Name"))
        marks.append(int(input("grade")))

    while total_marks < sum(marks):
        print('Invalid entry')
        marks = len(input('Re-enter the mark'))
    marks.append(marks)

    percent: int[Any] = []
    for i in range(len(marks)):
        percent.append(i / total_marks * 100)

    grade = []
    for j in range(len(percent)):
        if 90 <= j <= 100:
            grade.append("H1")
        elif 80 <= j <= 89:
            grade.append("H2")
        elif 70 <= j <= 79:
            grade.append("H3")
        elif 60 <= j <= 69:
            grade.append("H4")
        elif 50 <= j <= 59:
            grade.append("H5")
        elif 40 <= j <= 49:
            grade.append("H6")
        elif 30 <= j <= 39:
            grade.append("H7")
        elif 0 <= j <= 29:
            grade.append("H8")
    for i in range(num_students):
        print(names[i])
        
q6()
```

**Output:**

```
This is question 6!!!

Student grades


How many students would you like to enter?2

What is the total number of marks a student can get?200

NameMatthew

grade65

NameAltomare

grade85
Matthew
Altomare
```

Feel free to ask doubt if it is not clear.